# How to use tables for Luagl functions?

Tags: lua, luagl

Hello I'm trying to use Luagl to mess about with pixels and stuff however ran into a few issues with gl.DrawPixel() parameters which were not properly documented very excessively.

How do I use a lua table for this gl.DrawPixel() function?

This is what I've tried to do currently and the windows shows but there is no context shown because it's grey instead black also no pixels are shown as well.

Here is my code:

```
require("luagl")
require("wx")
require("math")


frame = nil
button = nil
testx = 0
testy = 0
checkimage = {0,100,0};
function render()
    context:SetCurrent(canvas)
    gl.ClearColor(0,0,0,0)
    --gl.PixelStore(gl.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)
    --gl.ShadeModel(gl.GL_FLAT)
    gl.Clear("COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT")

    gl.Begin('TRIANGLES')
            gl.Vertex( 0, 0.75, 0)
            gl.Vertex( -0.75, -0.75, 0)
            gl.Vertex( 0.75, -0.75, 0)
    gl.End()
    gl.DrawPixels(0,100, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,checkimage[0])
    canvas:SwapBuffers()
end


function main()

    frame = wx.wxFrame( wx.NULL ,
        wx.wxID_ANY,
        "Messing Around" ,
        wx.wxDefaultPosition,
        wx.wxSize(640,480),
        wx.wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE )

--~     button = wx.wxButton(frame , wx.wxID_NO,
--~     "bULLOCKS!", wx.wxDefaultPosition,
--~     wx.wxDefaultSize,wx.wxBU_EXACTFIT,
--~     wx.wxDefaultValidator, "Name")



    local filemenu = wx.wxMenu()
    filemenu:Append(wx.wxID_EXIT, "Exit" , "Quiting this shit!")

    local helpmenu = wx.wxMenu()
    helpmenu:Append(wx.wxID_ABOUT, "Blah!", "Hah!")

    local menubar = wx.wxMenuBar()
    menubar:Append(filemenu , "&file")
    menubar:Append(helpmenu , "&Help")

    frame:SetMenuBar(menubar)

    frame:CreateStatusBar(1)
    frame:SetStatusText("Welcome to WxLua")

    --button = wx.wxButton(panel,0 ,"Hellobutton")
    --button:SetDefault()

    frame:Connect(wx.wxID_EXIT, wx.wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,
        function (event) frame:Close(true) end )

    frame:Connect(wx.wxID_ABOUT , wx.wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,
        function(event)
            wx.wxMessageBox('Blah and more blah with blah',
                wx.wxOK + wx.wxICON_INFORMATION ,
                frame)
        end )

    canvas = wx.wxGLCanvas(frame, wx.wxID_ANY,
    wx.wxDefaultPosition, wx.wxDefaultSize, wx.wxEXPAND)

    context = wx.wxGLContext(canvas)


    canvas:Connect(wx.wxEVT_PAINT, render)

    canvas:Refresh()
    frame:Show(true)
end

main()

wx.wxGetApp():MainLoop()
```